# TSQL Question: Group by on multiple columns

Tags: t-sql, group-by, multiple-columns

I have a table with multiple columns that represent occurrences of an action.

simpleTableExample

```
id  type $$$$$ value1 value2 value3 ... value15
--  ----  --   -----  -----  -----      -----
1    "I"   1    "a"    "b"    ""         ""
2    "O"   1    "a"    "d"    "f"        "z"
3    "I"   1    "d"    "b"    ""         ""
4    "O"   1    "g"    "l"    ""         ""
5    "I"   1    "z"    "g"    "a"         ""
6    "I"   1    "z"    "g"    "a"         "a"
```

not really sure how to represent the data, but the above should show it... Per row, I have multiple columns that I want to group by. Focusing on the "a" part, I'd like the output such that :

```
Type     Value    Count  Sum
-----    -----    -----  ---
"I"      "A"      "3"     3
"O"      "A"      "2"     1
```

Just not sure how to go about, or even the best way, to group by with multiple columns. If it was a "tall" table with a sequence number, it'd be a snap...

One thing I'm worried about... is if I have the same value in multiple rows (they have the same action done multiple times), and I stack the columns and try to sum rows. So for example row 6 has 3 and 15 with value of a, and I try to Sum() the totals of that group, I don't want 6 counted twice (shown above

**Edit:** 
Trying to clarify here... I have a row of customers with "actions". The actions are collapsed into value1 thru value15. I want to get a count of "type, value" groups.

The count I had earlier was wrong... I want the distinct customers that have had a certain action, not the number of certain actions. So I-A should be a count of 4, using the above visible table.

**Final Note**[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/490/tame-this-beast-tsql-unpivot) question for what I came up with. Unpivot to build a list of unique date/value pairs.

Comment: It's not clear from your data where the `5` and `2` come from.

Comment: @Quassnoi the 5 and 2 are the number of columns that contain `a` for each type

Comment: @msarchet: in the data I see `2` columns for `O` and `3` (or `4` if counting duplicates), but not `5` columns for `I`.

Comment: If you unpivot this, you'd a count of 6 for "a" because it occurs twice in the row id=6. Can manage this, but what other rules are there?

Comment: Yeah... The count should be number of times A happens... grouped by type.

Comment: @WernerCD: yeah to who? me or Quassnoi?

Comment: Updated question... I had confused myself here in the example.

Comment: I appreciate you're guys help, even if I'm confusing things. I think I've over-thought this problem and am making it worse than it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL 2005 or greater you can use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) and then do your GROUP BYs and COUNTs

Comment: Reading up on unpivot now... I think it's what I'm looking for. Never seen/used it before.

Comment: I think I got unpivot to do what I wanted... I'll have to post what I came up with, and see how many WTF's I get.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/490/tame-this-beast-tsql-unpivot if you want to see my unpivot

Comment: @WernerCD wow it was 40 values fields. Lucky you're in 2005, otherwise you would have had to have gone with Ken Downs' approach

Comment: Well... I actually have two different sets of queries (one is 15 other is 40). I think its not as bad as it could have been, but still a bit unwieldy. Union All was on the plate, but I"m glad unpivot actually seems to work. A bit of why: The data originates from a COBOL Database which is 40 wide for that particular field... translated to SQL... combined with other data and written to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option to put that table in First Normal Form and break those repeating columns out to a child table?  Because, if we put aside the theory of why 1NF is good, the practical reality is that non-normalized examples like this make simple queries tough.

With that being said, if you are stuck with this non-normalized table, you have to code up something like this:

```
select type
     , 'A' as Column2
     , sum(case when value1='A' or value2='A' or.....
               then 1 else 0 end) as theCount
  from theTable
 group by type
```

If you want to query for multiple values, not just 'A', you have to pivot the table in the query, which involves oh about 15 unions:

```
select type,value,count(*) from (
    select type,value1 as value from theTable
    union all
    select type,value2 as value from theTable
    union all
    select type,value3 as value from theTable
    ...and so on...
) x
group by type,value
```